# Kemal framework - undefined constant HTTP::FormData

Tags: crystal-lang, kemal

I'm trying to set up a web app using the kemal framework written in the crystal language. I followed the tutorial mentioned in the getting started guide [here](http://kemalcr.com/docs/getting_started/)

However, I can't get even the most basic web app to work. The line `Kemal.run` gives an error which traces to the line `lib/kemal/src/kemal/param_parser.cr:69` and shows this error `undefined constant HTTP::FormData`.

I found the `HTTP::FormData` module https://github.com/RX14/multipart.cr. Adding this as a dependency and requiring it does not help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using an old version of Crystal. Check with `crystal -v`.

HTTP::FormData has been added [in Crystal 0.21.0](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.21.0/HTTP/FormData.html).

Comment: Thanks. Had Crystal 0.20.5